# Filter JavaScript object by key's prefix and reduce to build new objects

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I'm pulling from a large data dump API and need to filter the data better. Currently, this is an example of what I am seeing.

```
{
  AA-Short: "information",
  AA-Long: "more information",
  AA-Extra: "even more information",
  BB-Short: "information",
  BB-Long: "more information",
  BB-Extra: "even more information",
}
```

I'm trying to make this:

```
{
  AA: {
     AA-Short: "information",
     AA-Long: "more information",
     AA-Extra: "even more information"
  },
  BB: {
     BB-Short: "information",
     BB-Long: "more information",
     BB-Extra: "even more information"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you posr what you have tried please ?

Comment: @brk it is valid as long as you put it between quote

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. This is simply a matter of looping the properties, capturing the prefixes, and creating the objects ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
const data = {
  "AA-Short": "information",
  "AA-Long": "more information",
  "AA-Extra": "even more information",
  "BB-Short": "information",
  "BB-Long": "more information",
  "BB-Extra": "even more information",
};
const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
const groupedData = dataKeys.reduce((result, currKey) => {
  // Pull out the group name from the key
  const group = currKey.split('-')[0];
  // Check if the group exists, if not, create it
  const hasGroup = result[group] !== undefined;
  if (!hasGroup)
    result[group] = {};
  // Add the current entry to the result
  result[group][currKey] = data[currKey];
  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: This is what I was super close to making. It was the `hasGroup` section that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the object using `for..in` then use `substring` to get the first two characters. Create a new object and check if there exist a key whose name matches with the first two characters then add the value

```js
let x = {
  "AA-Short": "information",
  "AA-Long": "more information",
  "AA-Extra": "even more information",
  "BB-Short": "information",
  "BB-Long": "more information",
  "BB-Extra": "even more information"
}

let newObject = {}
for (let key in x) {
  let firstChars = key.substring(0, 2);
  if (!newObject.hasOwnProperty(firstChars)) {
    newObject[firstChars] = {};
    newObject[firstChars][key] = x[key]
  } else {
    newObject[firstChars][key] = x[key]
  }
}
console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what can be done

```js
let data = {
  "AA-Short": "information",
  "AA-Long": "more information",
  "AA-Extra": "even more information",
  "BB-Short": "information",
  "BB-Long": "more information",
  "BB-Extra": "even more information",
}


for (let i in data) {
  // get part of the path
  path = i.split("-") // e.g. ["AA", "Short"]

  // remove the last
  path.pop()

  // go into the tree creating a new node for each step if needed
  subdata = data
  for (let j of path) {
    if (typeof subdata[j] === "undefined") {
      subdata[j] = {}
    }
    subdata = subdata[j]
  }

  // put the datas when reaching the end of the path
  subdata[i] = data[i]
  // delete the original data
  delete data[i]
}

console.log(data)
```

use this one if you get thing like

```
"AA-Short": "information",
"AA-Short-Short": "info"
```

**AND** all values are `string`

```js
let data = {
    "AA-Short": "information",
    "AA-Short-Short": "info",
    "BB-Short": "information",
    "BB-Short-Short": "info"
}


for (let i in data) {
  // get part of the path
  path = i.split("-") // e.g. ["AA", "Short"]

  // remove the last
  path.pop()

  // go into the tree creating a new node for each step if needed
  subdata = data
  for (let j of path) {
    if (typeof subdata[j] === "undefined") {
      subdata[j] = {}
    }
    subdata = subdata[j]
  }

  // put the datas when reaching the end of the path
  subdata[i] = new String(data[i])
  // delete the original data
  delete data[i]
}

console.log(data)
```

the output can make it look like it break everything but that's actually correct since `String` is an array of char

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for..in` loop and check upon keys inside the loop, by splitting over `-` and creating respective objects:

```
let result = {};

for (v in data) {
  let key = v.split("-")[0];
  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key))
    result[key] = {};
  result[key][v] = data[v];
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  "AA-Short": "information",
  "AA-Long": "more information",
  "AA-Extra": "even more information",
  "BB-Short": "information",
  "BB-Long": "more information",
  "BB-Extra": "even more information",
};

let result = {};

for (v in data) {
  let key = v.split("-")[0];
  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key))
    result[key] = {};
  result[key][v] = data[v];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if a CC key exist ?

Comment: @executable I edited the answer to make it more dynamic and more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of the same map-reduce algorithm

```
const start = {
  "AA-Short": "information",
  "AA-Long": "more information",
  "AA-Extra": "even more information",
  "BB-Short": "information",
  "BB-Long": "more information",
    "BB-Extra": "even more information",
};

const aa = new Set(Object.keys(start).filter(k => k.split("-")[0] === "AA"));

const bb = new Set(Object.keys(start).filter(k => k.split("-")[0] === "BB"));

const rAA = {};
const rBB = {};

const result = Object.entries(start)
  .reduce((result, [k, v]) => {
    if (aa.has(k)) {
      return {
        ...result,
        AA: {
          ...result.AA,
          [k]: v
        }
      };
    }
    if (bb.has(k)) {
      return {
        ...result,
        BB: {
          ...result.BB,
          [k]: v
        }
      };
    }
    throw new Error("Unexpected key");

  }, {AA: {}, BB: {}});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys of the object and reduce them into the new object as follow:

```
let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {    // for each key in obj
  let newKey = key.split("-")[0];                       // get the sub key
  if(acc[newKey]) {                                     // if there is already an object for this sub key in the accumulator
    acc[newKey][key] = obj[key];                        // add the current object to it
  }
  else {                                                // otherwise
    acc[newKey] = { [key]: obj[key] };                  // create a new object for this sub key that initially contains the current object
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**Example:**

```js
let obj = { "AA-Short": "information", "AA-Long": "more information", "AA-Extra": "even more information", "BB-Short": "information", "BB-Long": "more information", "BB-Extra": "even more information" };

let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  let newKey = key.split("-")[0];
  if(acc[newKey]) {
    acc[newKey][key] = obj[key];
  }
  else {
    acc[newKey] = { [key]: obj[key] };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```